# Same user id for two different users using two different Facebook applications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible for two Facebook users using two different Facebook application to get **same** `id` when using graph api? I am asking because `id` is app scope based.

To clarify, I am thinking of this Api endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id&access_token={{access_token}}`

For example:

Let's say that we have two Facebook applications: `CatLovers` and `DogLovers`, and two Facebook users: `Sergey` and `Mark`. `Sergey` is using `CatLovers` application and `Mark` is using `DogLovers` application.

Can `Mark` and `Sergey` get same `id` for this two requests:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id&access_token={{MARKS_access_token_using_DOGLOVERS_application}}`

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id&access_token={{SERGEYS_access_token_using_CATLOVERS_application}}`

?

[Facebook Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you refer to map users across different apps here? This can be done via the business mapping api: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: That is correct! I am already planning of using business for apps, but I don't want to have two users in database with the same Facebook user id (one user came from `DogLovers` application and other user came from `CatLovers` application). I am familiar with `token_for_business`, but I would like to be sure that user ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask, whether ids from two *different apps* for two *different users* might be the same; so the possibility to get an id collision when working with two apps.

To answer your question, every Facebook ID for every object/user/page/etc. is unique, even for different apps. 
You won't get any id collisions here.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook ID is of type numeric string. This is a string that looks like a number. Are you trying to store the id as an int? You should be storing this in a string!